# Lombok: Shouldn't protected setters not be accessible by non-subclasses?

Tags: java, lombok

I am new to lombok and confused by why the following code compiles without any errors. Since I have specified the Setter to have `AccessLevel.PROTECTED`, shouldn't there be some sort of compile errors?

AnotherClass.java

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnotherClass {

    @Getter @Setter
    private int width;

    @Getter(AccessLevel.PUBLIC) @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    private int height;

    @Getter @Setter @NonNull
    private String name;
}
```

Main.java

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnotherClass instance1 = new AnotherClass(2, 1, "instance1");
    System.out.println("Fetching height of instance1: " + instance1.getHeight());
    instance1.setHeight(3);
    System.out.println("Fetching height of instance1: " + instance1.getHeight());
}
```

output:

```
Fetching height of instance1: 1
Fetching height of instance1: 3
```

Comment: If `Main` is in the same package as `AnotherClass`, then the protected members are accessible to it.

Comment: In Java `protected` means the element is visible to subclasses, regardless of package, and other classes within the same package.

Comment: Oh my bad! Am I correct to assume there isn't an access modifier that allows access to all code in a file and sub-classes only? Protected in Java doesn't seem to be like protected in other languages like C++ and C#. It seems like the only way to get the behavior I want is via combination of protected AND package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `delombok` to check that the generated setters are indeed 'protected'. As the comments indicate, java's access levels is a strict ascension; every more permissive level includes all access 'below' it. Thus:

- `private` = More or less: All code in this file.
- nothing (package private) = All of `private` + all source code in the same package.
- `protected` = **all of the above** + subclasses, even in another package.
- `public` = everything.

DISCLAIMER: I'm a lombok developer.